# Create a subobject from the superobject

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance

I have object1 of class Class1. I would like to extend class Class1 to Class2 adding one method and then create object2 of Class2 that would behave in all methods exactly as object1, except that now it would have an additional method.

```
Class1 object1 = new Class1();
Class2 object2 = new Class2(object1);
object2.oldMethod();
object2.newMethod();
```

object1.oldMethod should have exactly the same behaviour as object2.oldMethod. A stupid way would be to write a script that would generate the new class with all more than 100 inherited methods from Class1:

```
public class Class2 {
    private final Class1 object1;
    public Class2(Class1 object1) {
         this.object1 = object1;
    }

    public void oldMethod() {
        object1.oldMethod();
    }
    ...
    public void newMethod() {
    ...
    }
}
```

But I would like to be smarter than that. How?

**EDIT:**
I am sorry for not making it more explicit. I get object1 from some 3rd party, this object comes with some internal state - say some setters were ran on it before. I need to get object2 with the same internal state (this is what I mean by the same behaviour when a method is executed). I cannot just extend Class1, then get object2 from Class2. How will object2 know about the state of object1? I do not know the internal state (variables, arrays, fields) of the object1.

**EDIT2:**
I want to wrap object1, but do not want to have to write 100 wrapper methods for what stays the same.

Comment: What is preventing you from including the `newMethod` in Class1?

Comment: Yeahp... sounds like inheritance to me! `extends` keyword to the rescue

Comment: I do not have permissions to modify Class1 and object1 is provided for me from their API.

Comment: You dont have to modify the class1, all that you need is it to be visible.

Comment: Could you please be more specific how I can include newMethod in Class1 without modifying it?

Comment: [@dt1510](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1051522/dt1510) "*`object1.oldMethod()` should have exactly the same behaviour as `object2.oldmethod()`*". If `Class 1` extends `Class 2` then `object1.oldMethod()` should be exactly the same as `object2.oldMethod()` unless you override it?

Comment: If I modify Class1 and push the changes to everybody (more than 1000 devs), nobody will approve my newMethod. That is why I need to create something custom just for myself and my project.

Comment: I think what he actually wants is to ___wrap___ his object, not extend it.  I think what he is interested in is adding something like an ID number to the object, for use storing it in a data structure or the like, not actually making it perform some extra function.

Comment: Yes, I want to wrap it but do not want to have to write 100 wrapper methods for what stays the same.

Comment: The solution is to just use the wrapper's object getter to retrieve the object itself whenever you want to call the object's methods.

Comment: But then Class2 will not be able to extend Class1. So I will not be able to use object2 as a substitute for an object1.

Comment: Does `Class1` implement an interface?  If it does, you have the capability of creating a *dynamic proxy* for that interface that holds `object1`, and unless you specifically change things, send any method in that interface to `object1`.  You can have the proxy intercept one or two methods to do something different, and you can have the proxy use `object1` to perform new methods.  You don't need `Class1`'s source code, but you need that interface.  But if you need to modify a lot of `Class1`'s behavior, perhaps you should try AspectJ.

Comment: @EricJablow I didn't know there was a good way to do that in java.  I though doing something like that required some yucky reflection stuff.

Comment: It does require yucky reflection stuff.  For a more packaged version, AspectJ provides *introductions* where the AspectJ compiler actually modifies the compiled byte-code.  Spring has a more attenuated version of this, but it's suitable really only for modifying Spring-managed beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use inheritance unless `Object1` has a copy constructor because you are receiving an instance of `Object1` from the API and not constructing it yourself.

What you probably want is called the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). In this pattern, a decorator is composed of another object and adds functionality to the object via the decorator.

```
class Object1 {
    //...stuff...
}

class Decorator {
    private Object1 object;
    public Decorator(Object1 obj) {
        object = obj;
    }
    public Object1 getComposite() {
        return object;
    }
    public void extra() {
        //Do stuff with object1 and any other state specific to the decorator
    }
}
```

This could be done as inheritance as well, but only makes sense if you are really trying to extend the interface of `Object1` as opposed to simply enhancing the interface.

As a separate note, I don't think it is wise to actually try to extend a third party class unless the documentation makes it clear that the class is **designed for extension**. It is possible that future versions will have the class marked as `final` or that constructing the class may be complicated or made to have package/private access. Also, based on your edit, it may not even be possible. `Object1` would need a **copy constructor** in order to allow you to extend it and construct an instance of `Object2` from an `Object1`.

Comment: Yes, I have to extend the interface of object1.

Comment: How can I call decorator.oldMethod()?

Comment: You would have to do something like `decorator.getComposite().oldMethod()`.

Comment: You are right, in my case, the third party Class1 can change anytime and that would break my code.

Comment: I guess another note would be that if `Object1` implements an interface `IFoo` then you could have the decorator implement `IFoo` and use Eclipse IDE to generate delegate methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Class2 extends Class1{
    //signature of old method, with the same parameters (if exists).
    public void oldMethod(){
        super.oldMethod(); //call the Class1 method
        //do what you have to do for this class down here.
    }
}
```

This behaviour is known as polymorphism, where you delegate to the superclass what is generic and only implements what's really important for the class you're already working.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly declare `oldMethod`, by virtue of inheritance (dynamic dispatch and virtual methods) `Class2` will just use `Class1.oldMethod`

Comment: hes overriding the `oldMethod()` in order to be able to add more stuff

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Class1{
    public void methodx(){

    }
}

class Class2 extends Class1{
    public void extraMethod(){

    }

}
```

Inheritence is the perfect case. Here `methodx` is going to be inherited with exactly same behaviour as defined in `class1` and in `class2` you can have a new behaviour defined which is going to be perticular to `class2`.

Comment: How can I pass object1 to Class2 to get the object2 with the exactly same behavior but the extraMethod? If I cannot do that, then object2 is of no use to me.

Comment: I get your question now. Here is the question for you: even if this object comes from third party, do you think you can refer to this without having class? Class1 object1;  here how will you compile this code unless you have Class1 or any other super type of Class1

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for inheritance. Elaborating the comment of zerocool, you can declare Class2 extending Class1.

```
Class Class1{
    public void methodx(){

    }
}

class Class2 extends Class1{
    public void extraMethod(){

    }

}
```

Then you can still have a

```
Class1 obj = new Class2();
```

This will give you a Class2 obj with the Class1 reference.

IF you really want a data convertor from Class2 to Class1, you could write a an overloaded constructor of Class2 which takes a Class1 object like following:

```
public Class2 (Class1 obj)
{
    this.setName(obj.getName()); //Assuming name attribute
    ... // and other setter methods
}
```

**EDIT:**

As a wrapper you can do the following:

```
public class Class2
{
    private Class1 obj;

    public Class1 getClass1Obj()
    {
        return obj;
    }

    public void newMethod()
    {
        // your method here
    }
}
```

The old methods can be called on the object returned by `getClass1Obj()` and directly call `newMethod()` on object of `Class2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are close, my precise question is how I can avoid these `setName` methods. I do not want to generate more than 100 setters.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, but unfortunately I cannot use the wrapper class object as a substitute for the original object since Class2 does not extend Class1 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following with [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/) and the ajc compiler.

```
// Class1Extensions.aj
aspect Class1Extensions {
    // An inter-type declaration
    public void Class1.newMethod() {
       //...
    }
}
```

You will need to compile with `ajc` so that the code calling `object1.newMethod()` doesn't rebel.  You can also create an interface for `newMethod` and put into that aspect:

```
declare parents Class1+ implements Class1NewMethods;
```

Then, you can write

```
Class1NewMethods object2 = (Class1NewMethods) object1;
object2.newMethod();
```